# Surface view benefits for simple bitmap draw

Tags: android, view, bitmap, surfaceview

I need to draw a fullscreen Background and scroll it in a lot of situations. Actually I have implemented it as a normal View.

would I get any benefit just changing to SurfaceView? I don't think I even will need a separate thread, as the onDraw just contains a draw(huge)Bitmap().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `SurfaceView` is more designed for multithreading and drawing lots of objects. It can even be slower than a custom view if it's just to draw a bitmap, as a `SurfaceView` has an internal view hierarchy and more overhead than a `View` (initialization, ...).